# Php file upload returning error "not allowed" in server console

Tags: php, file, upload

I'm trying to learn php and upload files to my server following this guide:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

I feel like I followed it pretty well, and I am using HTTP file server 2.3e as my server software.

After I load up my image in the form and hit submit I get the following error within the server "Upload failed for v.png: Not allowed."

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
file_uploads = on;
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
file_uploads = on;
```

This is required to be in the php.ini not in the script (this also cannot be set by ini_set).  Add/look for file_uploads in your php.ini file and either change it to On or 1 and restart your http server.

Comment: So, I added a php.ini file to the same directory as everything else, and I removed the semi-colon from the end of "file_uploads=on", saved everything, and restarted the server.  However, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: the php.ini file needs to be in the same place it was originally (wherever your http config is looking for php configuration).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense.  However, inside the server's .ini file there is no such setting as "file_uploads" or anything close to it.  Whenever I try to manually add it once the server is turned on or off the line is removed.  Also, I tried manually navigating to the folder without using my html form or my php script and uploading it using the default browser's UI and it worked.  So I think it's an actual issue with the script...

Comment: if the php.ini is being replaced then you may need to edit the correct one (possibly its copying it from somewhere else when it starts up).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. turns how the server software I was using (HFS) didn't support php and "upload failed" was its was of telling me that.